Unable to access my Express in Minikube from browser
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: backend-configmap
  namespace: infra
data:
  MAX_AGE: "3600"
  PORT_NUMBER: "4000"
  ORIGIN: frontend-service
  SERVER: backend-service

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: backend-secret
  namespace: infra
type: Opaque
data:
  DATABASE_URL: bW9uZ29kYitzcnY6Ly9zaWRkaGFudGcyMDAyOnV1OUdXV0lWVlR1UmhPNjlAY2x1c3RlcjAubHF6aGpkZC5tb25nb2RiLm5ldC9Vc2Vycw==
  JWT_SECRET: Y2IxZjgzZDRjODVkZGY3ZmVjMjViZmM5NmEwMGM3OWYwMWQxMDAzZjFlN2Q1NmViNDJhMDMxZmZiY2RjOGQ1Yg==

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deployment
  namespace: infra
  labels:
    app: express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: express
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: express
        image: dedsec2002/testing:backend-minikube
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4000
        env:
        - name: DATABASE_URL
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: backend-secret
              key: DATABASE_URL
        - name: JWT_SECRET
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: backend-secret
              key: JWT_SECRET
        - name: MAX_AGE
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: backend-configmap
              key: MAX_AGE
        - name: PORT_NUMBER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: backend-configmap
              key: PORT_NUMBER
        - name: ORIGIN
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: backend-configmap
              key: ORIGIN
        - name: SERVER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: backend-configmap
              key: SERVER
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: docker-login

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
  namespace: infra
spec:
  selector:
    app: express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000


I've been trying to access my containerized Express app deployed in Minikube but haven't had any success. I've tried both `NodePort` and `LoadBalancer` service types. Even when using `minikube service backend-service -n infra`, I'm unable to access it through the browser. The pod logs indicate that the backend is running successfully, but the browser shows a "Cannot GET" error instead of the expected "Hello World" message.

the error suggesting that your application isn't responding. If you see errors in the pod logs, troubleshoot those issues. If you get an error with curl, it indicates a networking problem between your local machine and the Minikube VM.
Example : curl http://<minikube-ip>:<node-port>
use command : kubectl logs <pod-name\> -n infra to check for any errors within your container.
